# cx_oracle missing right parenthesis

Tags: python, sql, select, cx-oracle

I am using the cx_oracle python library to find any records that have a modifiedDate in the last 90 minutes.

```
import cx_Oracle
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import config as config

timeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
previousTime = timeNow - datetime.timedelta (minutes = 0)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, connection)
cur = connection.cursor()
statement = "SELECT * FROM woodburn_all WHERE modifiedDate >= to_date(" + str(previousTime) +")"
print statement
r = cur.execute(statement)
for row in cur:
    print row
```

The printed select statement looks correct:

`SELECT * FROM woodburn_all WHERE to_date(modifiedDate) >= to_date(2018-09-2 11:02:10.460000)`

I'm not seeing where I'm missind anything parenthesis. Is this some weird date/time thing?

EDIT: Using Python v2.7

Comment: Most probably this error is coming from `print statement`. Replace it with `print (statement)` if you are using `python 3+`. Same applies to `print row` if it's python 3+

Comment: Don't use string concatenation. `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM woodburn_all WHERE modifiedDate >= to_date(%s)",  (previousTime,))`. Some versions of SQL require `?` rather than `%s`, I'm not sure which is required here.

Comment: Use a "prepared statement" with `?` as parameters, and forget about this problem.

Comment: Printed statement does not look correct. You need to enclose date in single quotes. Otherwise it is like you're subtracting some digits and oracle expects a bracket or a comma (etc) after `2018-09-2`.

Comment: @SalmanA - If I add in single quotes around the timestamp I then get an error , `date format picture ends before converting entire input string`.  New statement = `statement = "SELECT * FROM woodburn_all WHERE modifiedDate >= to_date('" + str(previousTime) +"')"` and printed output looks like `SELECT * FROM woodburn_all WHERE modifiedDate >= to_date('2018-09-20 10:01:51.242000')`

Comment: The error is guiding you in right direction. You need to secify the format as he second parameter. See https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: @SalamA  - OK, so I added the following, `cur.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'") 
statement = "SELECT responseid, TO_CHAR(modifiedDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM woodburn_all WHERE modifiedDate >='" + formatedTime +"'"`
This clears w/o errors but doens't return any records where it should which tells me that something about this format isn't being recognized by the oracle DB.

Comment: Instead of altering session variables, try `>= to_date('2018-09-2 11:02:10.460000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`. If it complains about `.460000` then chop off the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
your problem in sql statement where clause
 to_date(2018-09-2 11:02:10.460000)
```

because if you write this in oracle

```
select  to_date(2018-09-2 11:02:10.460000) from dual this will trrow
```

1. ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, when any sql statement syntax error occur oracle engine thrown this error

so it would be like this

```
select TO_DATE('09/02/2018 13:27:18', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

so your where clause will be

```
TO_DATE('09/02/2018 13:27:18', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: thanks fot the suggestion. I tired doing what you suggested, `statement = "SELECT * FROM woodburn_all WHERE modifiedDate >= to_date(" + str(previousTime) +",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')"` but still get the same error.

Comment: So, This solution finally work for me: 
`statement = "SELECT VENDORCONTRACT, APPSTATUS FROM woodburn_all WHERE modifiedDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('" + str(formatedTime) +"') AND TO_DATE('"+ str(timeNowFormated) + "')"`
which took into account what @SalmanA suggested with the single quotes and  all of the formating comments YYYY-MM-DD. For the formatting in cx_oracle I ran an alter session statement before my select execute statement to account for timestamp formatting
`cur.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'")` thanks

Comment: Please do not use "+" to build up the SQL statement - in this case you will reduce DB performance & scalability.  In other cases it is also a SQL Injection security risk.  Use bind variables as explained in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you are passing an unquoted string item to your Oracle query. As @TheImpaler mentioned in comments, simply use [parameterization](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html) which will handle quotes and literals.

Additionally, use `strftime` to convert the datetime object to your needed string format. In fact doing so, you do not need to subtract minutes:

```
time_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

# PREPARED STATEMENT
statement = "SELECT * FROM woodburn_all WHERE modifiedDate >= to_date(:1, :2)"

# PASSING TUPLE OF PARAMS
r = cur.execute(statement, (time_now, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'))

for row in r:
    print(row)
```

Comment: No need for two parameters (IMO). The date format could be embedded in the query.

Comment: Correct @SalmanA ... but I am illustrating multiple params as OPs usually think a one-item tuple is an error: `(time_now,)`

Comment: @ Parfait - 

`timeNow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
statement =  "SELECT * FROM woodburn_all WHERE modifiedDate >= to_date(:1, :2)"
r = cur.execute(statement,(timeNow,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24: MI'))`

does not return any records when it should

Comment: Did you really put a space in front of `MI`? Also send a hard-coded query (no variables or params) and see if you can reproduce.

Comment: What happens if you pass: `SELECT * FROM woodburn_all WHERE modifiedDate >= to_date('2018-09-20 13:15', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')`?